# Access 2007 Front End won't open linked sql server express 2014 recordset. Why?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, linker, dao, upsizing

I am trying to upgrade an Access 2007 Backend database to Sql Server Express 2014 because it is too slow across a network now.

I was able to upsize the db and link the tables back into my Access Front End using built in ODBC linking functionality.

Here is simple code that worked fine with the access backend but fails with SQl Server Express: "Runtime Error 3021 - No Current Record"

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim strHST As String
  Dim recHST As DAO.Recordset

  Set db = CurrentDb()

  strHST = "SELECT * FROM tblHST WHERE hst_current = -1;"
  Set recHST = db.OpenRecordset(strHST, dbOpenDynaset)

 With recHST
      .MoveFirst
      Me!txtHST = !hst_rate
      Me!txtHSTPK = !hst_auto
 End With

  recHST.close
  set recHST = nothing
  db.close
  set db = nothing
End Sub
```

I also tried Set recHST = db.OpenRecordset(strHST, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges) without any luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the datatype of the `hst_current` field in the SQL Server table?

Comment: Do you get a non-empty recordset with this query? `SELECT * FROM tblHST WHERE hst_current <> 0;`

Comment: Ahhh. Now I see. It is boolean and -1 will not replace true. Problem solved but I have a lot of code to go through to find all instances where I have done that. Probably will encounter some other gems along the way too.